# what's the relationship between a.s. continuous and m.s. continuous?

Tags: stochastic-processes

suppose that X(t) is a s.p. on T with $EX(t)^2<+\infty$. we give two kinds of continuity of X(t).

1. X(t) is continuous a.s.
2. X(t) is m.s. continuous, i.e. $\lim\limits_{\triangle t \rightarrow 0}E(X(t+\triangle t)-X(t))^2=0$.

Then, what's the relationship between these two kinds of continuity.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a clear relation between both concepts.

For example if you take the Brownian Motion it satisfies 1 and 2 but if you take a Poisson process then it only satisfies 2 (although it satisfies a weaker form of condition 1 which is continuity in probability).

The question is what do you want to do with those processes ?

Regards

Comment: can you give an example satisfying 1 but not satisfying 2?

Comment: @Jim : I think that it is true that 1 implies 2 under existence of second moment and an additionnal domination assumption. Take $t_n \to t$ then $Y_n=(X_{t_n}-X_t)^2$ is positive r.v., if the sequence $X_{t_n}$ is bounded by an $L^1$ variable $Z$ (and so $Y_n$) then dominated convergence theorem shows implication 1=>2 under the condition that domination is true for all such sequence converging to $t$. So to exhibit a counter-example you should find a process such that this cannot be done but I'm not sure how to do that or if it is possible, also maybe the condition might be weakened. Regards

Answer (score 1):

For an example which is a.s. but not m.s. continuous, take your time interval to be $[0, \infty]$, and let $X_t$ be a standard one-dimensional Brownian motion started at 0 and stopped the first time it reaches 1.  (That is, if $B_t$ is a standard Brownian motion, take $T = \inf\{t > 0 : B_t = 1\}$ and $X_t = B_{t \wedge T}$.)  Since Brownian motion is recurrent, we have $X_t \to 1$ a.s. as $t \to \infty$, and so by setting $X_{\infty} = 1$ we get an a.s. continuous stochastic process on $[0,\infty]$.

However, $X_t$ is not m.s. continuous.  If it were, then by Cauchy-Schwarz we would have $E[X_t] \to E[X_\infty] = 1$ as $t \to \infty$.  But $X_t$ is a martingale and so $E[X_t] = 0$ for all $t \in [0,\infty)$.

If you don't like using $[0,\infty]$ as your time interval, then apply a time change: let
$$Y_t = \begin{cases} X_{t/(1-t)}, & t < 1 \\ 1, & t \ge 1.\end{cases}$$
Now $Y_t$ is a.s. continuous but $E[Y_t] = 0$ for $t < 1$, $E[Y_t] = 1$ for $t \ge 1$.  Note that $Y_t$ is a standard example of a local martingale which is not a martingale.